# Opening a new window in ASP.NET using VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

In my code behind, I need to open a little window that displays another aspx page. I have found many ways to do this in JavaScript, but haven't been able to find a way to do it using VB.Net.

Looks like you can call `window.open()` in JavaScript. Is there a VB.Net version of this call, or is this something that has to be done client side?

Comment: you need to learn the difference between client side and server side code. C# and VB.NET execute server side on the server and are unable to open popup or anything client side for which you must use JavaScript. You can use page_PreRender and attach a JavaScript call to the page or to a server control, but you are still writing out a JavaScript command into the page, window.open is JavaScript

Answer (score 4):

C# and VB.NET is server-side. Opening a new *client* window will have to be done client-side, so you'll have to use JavaScript to open a new window.

What you *could* do, is to create a JavaScript function listening to a service, which would open a popup window when it receives the correct data. Then in your code-behind, you call this web-service method, and the listener will fetch.

**Example JavaScript code using [jQuery](http://jquery.com)**

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        // check for changes
        $.get('ajax/websvc.aspx?checkForChanges=true', function(data) {
            // Verify data received
            if (data = "what i want") {
                window.open();
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to open a window after a call to a code-behind method, for example after the form is posted back to save some data, then you can execute create the javascript to open the window in code-behind and have this javascript code executed automatically when the source page is redisplayed to the user.

We use this mechanism all of the time to display wizards that can only be executed after the record on the page is saved.

For example:

```
string sScript = "window.open('newpage.aspx', '_blank');";
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyOpener", sScript, true);
```